# trying to search for element by more than one property

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm  writing a piece for code for selenium test

The idea is to search for element by different property and once he find the elem by any of property the action will be taken , i tried several method , but none of them are optimized

First way :

String identifier = x.getidentifier();

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
myStringArray[0]= ".className";
myStringArray[1]= ".name";
myStringArray[2]= ".id";
for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringArray.length ; i++){
 if (i==0){
    List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.className(identifier));     
}else if (i==1){
     List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.name(identifier));         
 }else if (i==2){
     List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.id(identifier));
 } 
 if (elems.size() != 0){
    break;
 }
}
```

the problem in this that it cannot see the last variable elems

and the second solutions is :

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
        myStringArray[0]= "className";
        myStringArray[1]= "name";
        myStringArray[2]= "id";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringArray.length ; i++){
        List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.+myStringArray[i](identifier));
}
```

and also it cannot do a concatenation like this , any ideas?

Comment: sorry i'm bit lost...u want to append all elements found via different properties in elems variable???

Comment: no , i want to find element by any or properties i wish to pass via external data file which is stored under identifier

Answer (score 0):

```
For the first code Snippet you can use this version of code

String[] myStringArray = new String[3];
        List<WebElement> elems;
        myStringArray[0]= ".className";
        myStringArray[1]= ".name";
        myStringArray[2]= ".id";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringArray.length ; i++){
         if (i==0){
            elems = driver.findElements(By.className(identifier));     
        }else if (i==1){
             elems = driver.findElements(By.name(identifier));         
         }else if (i==2){
             elems = driver.findElements(By.id(identifier));
         }   
        }
        if (elems.size() != 0){
            break;
         }
```

But the locator strategy should be based on User supplied/Scenario not on loop index.

You can use below code example to implement locator strategy.

```
if (strWebElementDescription.startsWith("(id)")) {
                objWebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                        .presenceOfElementLocated(By
                                .id(strWebElementDescription
                                        .replace("(id)", ""))));
```

strWebElementDescription can be Xpath, id description etc. append with locator strategy like (id) in above example.